# how to debug failed oozie workflows on Analytics for Apache Hadoop?

Tags: ibm-cloud, oozie, analytics-for-hadoop, analytics-for-apache-hdp

I'm trying to run an oozie workflow on Bluemix ***Analytics for Apache Hadoop***, but it it failing.  The output from calling Workflow status is as follows:

```
    ...
    {
      "errorMessage": "Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.ShellMain], exit code [1]",
      "status": "ERROR",
      "stats": null,
      "data": null,
      "transition": "fail",
      "externalStatus": "FAILED/KILLED",
      "cred": "null",
      "conf": "<shell xmlns=\"uri:oozie:shell-action:0.2\"> 
                  <job-tracker>****:8050</job-tracker>
                  <name-node>hdfs://****:8020</name-node>          
                  <configuration>
                     <property>      
                        <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>   
                        <value>default</value>
                     </property>
                  </configuration>  
                  <exec>/usr/bin/python</exec>
                  <argument>oozie_python.py</argument>
                  <file>oozie_python.py#oozie_python.py</file>
               </shell>",
      "type": "shell",
      "endTime": "Tue, 13 Oct 2015 17:00:05 GMT",
      "externalId": "job_1444057234209_0042",
      "id": "0000023-151005150325577-oozie-oozi-W@oozie-python",
      "startTime": "Tue, 13 Oct 2015 16:59:53 GMT",
      "externalChildIDs": null,
      "name": "oozie-python",
      "errorCode": "JA018",
      "trackerUri": "****:8050",
      "retries": 0,
      "toString": "Action name[oozie-python] status[ERROR]",
      "consoleUrl": "http://****:8088/proxy/application_1444057234209_0042/"
    },
    ...
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't help at all for debugging the error. The consoleUrl is not accessible.

**Question**: how can I debug this issue on Bluemix ***Analytics for Apache Hadoop***?

Comment: I am blessfully ignorant of what BlueMix is exacty, and I am more familiar with the Oozie CLI; but the REST API documentation has a section about "GET /oozie/v1/job/job-3?show=log >>> retrieves the job log" that might prove useful

Comment: And of course you can get to the YARN log for "application_1444057234209_0042" -- if you ever can find the correct server and port (the displayed URL is not reliable, indeed) -- using `curl` if you have no other choice.

Comment: Anyway Google hints that JA018 has something to do with `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` which does not make much sense for a Shell action. Bad setup? Missing the base Oozie ShareLib?? Good luck with that one...

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter - thanks for the info.  I'll try switching to a Java action instead of python.