# Are Oozie Java Actions supported with Analytics for Apache Hadoop?

Tags: ibm-cloud, analytics-for-hadoop, analytics-for-apache-hdp

I've been trying to run a [Shell Action](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/DG_ShellActionExtension.html) on ***Analytics for Apache Hadoop***, however I have run into some issues.  For more information, see [how to debug failed oozie workflows on Analytics for Apache Hadoop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33108767/how-to-debug-failed-oozie-workflows).

In response to the issues, I have asked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33120113/are-oozie-shell-actions-supported-with-analytics-for-apache-hadoop) asking if Analytics for Apache Hadoop supports Shell Actions.

--

**Question:** I would also like to know if Oozie Java Actions supported with Analytics for Apache Hadoop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just tested an Oozie Java Action on the Bluemix Analytics for Apache Hadoop service and can confirm that it worked.